# How do servers protect against straight up sending a HTTP request that is actually some malware or HTML code?

Tags: malware, http, vulnerability

I know servers have something to block you from just sending them an HTTP request that is actually some malware or a webpage that is malicious, because it would be so easy to just spam HTTP requests with malware. Code red used something more advanced than that by spamming an HTTP request with Ns. Also, I wonder if some servers don't have this patched?

Comment: In general they use www.modsecurity.org or similar software for that.

Comment: I think you're a bit confused about how web servers work. Sending malware to a webserver wouldn't do anything at all, and you also can't send a website to a webserver (at least, not in a meaningful way)

Answer (score 8):

[Here](https://i.redd.it/nmbbrs31r3h41.png) is an image of the SARS-CoV-2 genome. Will looking at the image give you COVID-19? Of course not. While you could call this the biological equivalent of "malicious code," it doesn't cause any harm unless it's presented in a format and context where it might be "executed."

The same concept applies to computers - code or data that is dangerous in one context can be completely inert in another context. If you send malicious code or data to a web server, unless it's specifically designed to target a flaw in the web server, it will just be treated as data and it will have no meaningful effect.

Comment: Really good analogy. And it made me think of [Snow Crash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snow_Crash)

Answer (score 4):

Servers don't protect against you sending anything at all. You can open `ncat` and upload any file you want, with or without wrapping it in HTTP headers, to any server on the Internet.

Of course, it won't *do* anything. Servers neither execute client-supplied code nor render HTML (at least, not by default or under any common situation), so sending them malware or HTML is kind of like... reading it aloud to a dog? The dog hears you but doesn't know what to do with what you sent it, and doesn't really care. That's what transmitting malware to a server is like.

Now, if there's a vulnerability in the server (a buffer overflow, or a file-planting attack, or an XML parsing vulnerability, etc.) and the server tries to handle requests using the vulnerable code path, then you can send a malicious request that exploits the vulnerability. Having done so, you might (depending on the exploit) be able to drop and execute some malware as a payload, or change the HTML that the server serves to clients, or something like that (or any of a number of other things). But, that's assuming that the server has a vulnerability, that this vulnerability is publicly exposed to the Internet, that you know about this vulnerability, and that it can be exploited to do something that you, the attacker, find useful for whatever your goal is.

---

If you're worried about malicious requests on your server - things that target either vulnerabilities in the server software, or in the web application that you're serving (assuming you're serving one, rather than just static content) - there are a few things you can do about that. The first and most important is of course to keep your software up to date, patching any known vulnerabilities as fast as possible. Another is minimizing attack surface; don't expose more ports, or more services, or more features, than your clients need. Finally, you can look at systems that attempt to block suspected-malicious requests. "Web Application Firewalls" (WAFs) are software or hardware modules that sit between the server and the Internet, and try to detect common attack patterns. You can also add security filtering in the server itself, as the first step before otherwise processing the request.

Note though, that just like anti-virus, WAFs and similar are not a reliable protection. If anything, they're a last-ditch effort to keep you safe long enough to fix things. Evading them is often easy if you know they're there, and sometimes happens by accident or habit. They also increase attack surface; the security module is itself parsing client requests, and if *it* has a vulnerability, then that's something an attacker could exploit! You'd hope that products intended to increase your security wouldn't introduce new vulnerabilities, but it has happened.